# Speed up local network (not internet)

Tags: networking

I have Ubuntu 10.04

Computer specs:

i5
16GB Memory
1TB hdd
1 Gigabit onboard network card
Asus P8H77MLE Motherboard

I have 10 users, logged in at the same time, using the computer as a server / terminal, and connecting to it.

The computer is very fast, but the people that log in locally have slow connections, and sometimes have to wait for a response.

What can I do?

Comment: Your question is slightly unclear and vague. Could you please clarify it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(this should be a comment rather than an "answer", I don't have enough rep to comment).

First of all, you should determine where the bottleneck is occurring. Is it truly the local network, or is it the tasks users are performing on the system?

One could use SNMP to help determine network bottlenecks and where they are occurring.

Comment: I am not sure where the bottleneck is happening. The on board network is way strong and big, as it is 1 Gigabyte network on board, and 10 users are requesting access at the same time to one computer....

I am not sure, what is the SNMP?

Is it software that I should download? 

let me know

Comment: SNMP is the "Simple Network Management Protocol". Assuming your networking devices support it, it can be used to monitor how much load each device is under.

It'll help to identify if there's a network bottleneck.

How is the computer connected to the rest of the network? What's the rough layout of the network?

Also, could you be more specific to *how* your users are connecting? SSH? Telnet?